# Spark Submit taking additional Containers

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

While doing a `Spark-submit` with static allocation the number of containers spawned are higher than the count mentioned in the num-executors manual submission. Any specific reasons why the jobs are taking up additional resources.

Spark - 2.4.4

```
spark-submit \
--name "name" \
--master "yarn" \
--deploy-mode "cluster" \
--queue "queue" \
--driver-memory "1g" \
--executor-memory "1g" \
--num-executors "10" \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=PYSPARK_PYTHON \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 \
--conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=512 \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=512 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100 \
--conf spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true \
--properties-file properties_file \
--archives ZIP_FILE \
--jars  JARS
```

Please do let me know if any additional information is required.

[image: YARN Resources Container]

Comment: I dont see `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false` in your parameters. Is it disabled cluster-wide?

Comment: @mazaneicha normally when doing a Spark-Submit we use the `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true` as the EMR cluster is scalable (considering that I feel its disabled cluster wide, though any way I can check on that to reconfirm). But I was just trying with a STATIC one where I have removed the config so and mention the memory and executors manually.

Comment: Please try with `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false` and see if it works. And I'd suggest to remove STATIC (in all caps!) from the title if you're not sure.

Comment: @mazaneicha that did the trick, great.. Buy the way can you tell me how to check if there is a cluster wide Dynamic allocation turned ON ? .. Also any reason for asking to remove the _static_ keyword in the title

Answer (score 0):

It seems like yarn didn't understand your request. I'm not sure, but may be quotes around 10 in `--num-executors "10"` are redundant.